# Layering dynamically created Canvases in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm currently working on a game to teach myself HTML5 and Javascript, etc.

Originally I just had static canvases in the HTML body but it became a pain to pass around to my objects, etc. Basically it's easier for me to let each object just create its own as needed.

However, I don't know how to layer them properly like I had before. Now I have have my different canvases stacked atop of each other (my background sits above the player icon and below the objects to avoid).

How do I do this? I know it's related to the z-index (maybe innerHTML) but I'm very n00bish with HTML Javascript.

Thanks!

```
    <canvas id="pointsCanvas"
style="z-index: 40;
position:absolute;
left:0px;
top:0px;
">
This text is displayed if your browser does not support HTML5 Canvas.
</canvas>

<canvas id="menuCanvas"
style="z-index: 50;
position:absolute;
left:0px;
top:0px;
">
This text is displayed if your browser does not support HTML5 Canvas.
</canvas>
```

I had this.

Now I'm trying this:

```
this.canvasElement = document.createElement('canvas')
```

Comment: Whithout any code or knowing exactly what you mean by "layers", we sure as heck don't know either ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add them to a container element with its position set to relative (preferably create a rule, not an inline style like in this example):

```
<div id="container" style="position:relative"></div>
```

Then add canvases with their position set to absolute and left/top to 0:

```
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
canvas.width = 500;
canvas.height = 400;
canvas.style.cssText = "position:absolute;left:0;top:0";

// add to container
document.getElementById("container").appendChild(canvas);
```

The first canvas added will be at the bottom, the last on top.

You *can* use z-indexes but it's better just to create and add canvases in the order you want, knowing first is bottom etc. (imo).

### Demo:

```js
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
canvas.width = 500;
canvas.height = 400;
canvas.style.cssText = "position:absolute;left:0;top:0";

var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.font = "80px sans-serif";
ctx.fillText("BOTTOM", 10, 120);

// add to element
document.getElementById("container").appendChild(canvas);

// SECOOND CANVAS

var canvas2 = document.createElement("canvas");
canvas2.width = 500;
canvas2.height = 400;
canvas2.style.cssText = "position:absolute;left:0;top:0";

var ctx2 = canvas2.getContext("2d");
ctx2.font = "80px sans-serif";
ctx2.fillStyle = "blue";
ctx2.fillText("TOP", 16, 120);

// add to element
document.getElementById("container").appendChild(canvas2);
```

```css
#container {position:relative}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A more traditional method is to have one canvas display multiple (layered) objects.

To do this you can create an array containing the definitions of each of your objects:

```
var gameObjects=[];

var gameObjects.push({
    type: 'rect',
    x:50, y:50,
    width:100, height:75,
    fill: 'red'
});

... and so on ...
```

Then for each game frame, you clear the canvas and use the definitions-array to draw the game objects in their new position.

```
// move the rect 5 pixels rightward
gameObjects[0].x += 5;

context.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);

for(var i=0;i<gameObjects.length;i++){
    var obj=gameObjects[i];
    if(i.type='rect'){ drawRect(obj); }
}

function drawRect(r){
    context.fillStyle=r.fill;
    context.fillRect(r.x,r.y,r.width,r.height);
}
```

**Layering**

To do layering, you can add a z-index property to each of your gameObjects. It's not a z-index like a traditional html/css z-index. Instead it just lets you sort your gameObjects into any order (layers) you need.

```
var gameObjects.push({
    type: 'rect',
    x:50, y:50,
    width:100, height:75,
    fill: 'red',
    zIndex=3
});

// sort the array by zIndex to apply layering
gameObjects.sort(function(a,b){return a.zIndex - b.zIndex});

// and now draw the "relayered" objects in the array
for(var i=0;i<gameObjects.length;i++){
    var obj=gameObjects[i];
    if(i.type='rect'){ drawRect(obj); }
}
```